# 3D coordinates to pixel coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, mapping, 2d

I'm writing code to simulate stereo vision and found some troubles with the 3D to 2D mapping. The object I'm looking at is built around the axes origin and the camera target is set to `[0 0 0]`.

Camera up-vector is `[0 0 1]` so that the camera reference system and world (object) reference system are the same. To map 3D points into 2D points I have:

```
[x/z y/z 1]' = K * P * [X Y Z 1]'
```

where `[x/z y/z]` are the pixel coordinates of the 3D point located at `[X Y Z 1]` using homogeneous notation. `K` is the `3 x 4` calibration matrix (last column made of zeros) and `P` is the `4 x 4` projection matrix.

Since I also need to simulate calibration process I've obtained `K` using the Matlab Calibration Toolbox from Caltech with a typical chess pattern (this one built in Matlab too). `K` is found to be:

```
K = [521 0   409 0;
     0   521 288 0;
     0   0   1   0]
```

where the focal lenght is set by the camera view angle and i'm using `800 x 600` pictures taken with command `print`.

---

**Here's my problem:** if in 3D view I put a marker at the origin of the axes and take a picture of the scene with camera placed at `[0 -50 -50]` (for example) looking at `[0 0 0]` as said before I found the pixel coordinates of the origin at `[415 290]` in the picture.

But trying to calculate the projection through `K * P * [0 0 0 1]'` I'm getting wrong results such as `[409 811 1]` where `X` is **almost** the same but `Y` is completely wrong (even outside the picture boundaries).

`K` is defined by calibration toolbox, `P` is defined by rotation just on X-axis (45° in this case) and translation at `[0 -50 -50]`.

What am i doing wrong?

Here's the `P` matrix (if it helps):

```
 P = [1  0      0     0;
      0  0.707 -0.707 -50;
      0  0.707  0.707 -50;
      0  0      0     1]
```

Comment: The projection matrix is defined is K[R|T] = P, and x = PX , so the equation x = KPX is what is wrong, however if P here is [R|T] then your computations are correct (I don't know about the [415, 290] thing though.)

Comment: The angle and the translation from the axes origin are known, so the only source of error is the matrix K i think. The "matlab focal lenght" is set by the camera view angle and i've used the same value for the images of the calibration pattern and the images of the object, so the zoom is not changing and K should be the same.